# Return json array from classic asp

Tags: json, asp-classic

I am returning html from classic asp. Here is my code :-

```vb
<% ListFolderContents(Server.MapPath("/userfiles")) %>
<% sub ListFolderContents(path)

 dim fs, folder, file, item, url

 set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 set folder = fs.GetFolder(path)
 Response.Write("<h2>"& folder.Name &"</h2>")
 for each item in folder.SubFolders
            ListFolderContents(item.Path)
 next
 Response.Write("<ul>")
 for each item in folder.Files

    Response.Write("<li><a>" & item.Name & "</a></li>")
 next
    Response.Write("</ul>")
 end sub
%>
```

But i want to return json array.I am new ,can anyone please guide me with any link or with any example.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have done this in ASP and it isn't fun.  You need to manually build the json string formatted with the hierarchy you are looking for. You can find tons of direction on formatting json in google.

Here is one example of formatted json from http://json.org/example

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

Following that, the only ASP specific thing I would recommend is to add this to the code that builds the response.

```
response.ContentType="application/json"
```